# Can visitor open a bank account in Germany?

Tags: germany, money, munich

I am in Munich for 2 months internship. Can anyone please tell if I can open a Bank account here in Munich, Germany ? What'd be the procedure?

Comment: Most banks want a proof of German residence for a bank account. If you work there you will need to register as a resident anyway and then the procedure is exactly the same as for any other resident. Flagging to move the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible. I opened a bank account a couple of years ago as a foreigner with just my passport and a certificate of residence (*Meldebestätigung*). You'll want an online bank probably, so that you can manage your account even when you go back to your country.

Most online banks use an identification procedure based on post offices (*Postident*). Essentially, you'll have to go to a post office with your passport, and that's it. After the account is opened you can change your contact details to your home address when you go back.

If you don't speak a word of German, the whole procedure might be tricky to carry out, though.

Be sure to start early; two months isn't much and you can run into unexpected delays.

(Word of warning: I am a EU citizen; I don't exclude that things might be more complicated for non-EU customers).